# SQL query query

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query to get list of Authors who have written at least a book on all Genres

Tables are

```
      Author_id  |  Author_info  => authors
      Genre_id   |  Genre_info   => genres
      Author_id  |  Genre_id  |  Book_id  => books
```

I'm using Mysql, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What did you try, what results did it gave you ?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself already? As a tip, start by finding authors where there is a gender that they have NOT written about. Those are the authors that you DON'T want.

Comment: My idea was counting the number of genres from 'genres' and then matching them with distinct mapping of (author_id,genre_id), but as I have been away from SQL for a while, I couldn't put it together in SQL

Comment: This is a good approach as well and it will probably be faster. The answer from Thilo is nice and does exactly this.

Comment: yes it is what i could do in English but needed someone like Thilo to put down as SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If N is the number of distinct genres:

```
select author_id, count(distinct genre_id) as genres
from books 
group by author_id 
having genres = N
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumed database schema as this

```
authors
|-  Author_id  -|- Author_info -|
genres
|-  Genre_id   -|- Genre_info  -|
books
|-  Author_id  -|-  Genre_id   -|-  Book_id -|
```

Query

```
SELECT authors.Author_id
FROM authors
LEFT INNER JOIN books ON (authors.Author_id = books.Author_id)
GROUP BY authors.Author_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT books.Genre_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM genres)
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Looking at the SQL I think it will aggregate the count across *all* books for *all* authors as there is no grouping by author.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Author_id
FROM books
INNER JOIN Genre USING (Genre)
GROUP BY Author_id
HAVING COUNT(Author_id) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Genre);
```

Answer (score 0):

For written at least a book on all Genres

Try...

```
select author_id, count(distinct genre_id) as genres
from books 
group by author_id 
having genres >= 1
```